# How to create a virtualized, reorderable list with dynamic sizes, and animated item adding and removal in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I need a flutter list package with the following features:

1. Only renders items in/near visible range (virtualized)
2. Supports different item heights.
3. Reorderable through drag and drop
4. When an item is dragged to the edge of the screen, the list scrolls
5. When items enter or exit, the list animates nicely

The package ReorderableListView.builder (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ReorderableListView/ReorderableListView.builder.html) supports 1,3 and 4. No support for 5. Reordering animation was bad for items with differing heights (2) when I tried it out.

The package implicitly_animated_reorderable_list
(https://pub.dev/packages/implicitly_animated_reorderable_list/changelog) supports 3 and 5. Nothing mentioned about 1 or 2 in its readme, and a comment from January here ([Flutter: Reorderable AND Animated ListView - any idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56719808/flutter-reorderable-and-animated-listview-any-idea)) suggests 4 is missing.

Looking for advice on how to achieve this:

- An amazing package that can do all 5.
- A way to add features of these different packages together somehow. Is that at all possible?
- Advice on forking or not forking and just starting from scratch.
- In regards to forking what in your opinion is the most/least trivial of these features to build from scratch?

I'm new to Flutter, so anything I don't know enough to ask about in relation to this subject is also greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Own answer:

There really isn't a need for any plugins or forks. `ReorderableListview.builder` can be used to accomplish all 5.

Not sure how I botched the code that made me think ReorderableListView.builder wasn't handling different heights of items correctly, but whatever the glitch was (maybe related to keys?), I'm not able to reproduce it. Interesting that all the docs/tutorials I found only show statically sized list items when dynamically sized list items are no problem.

As for the animated exits and entrances (i.e. not letting the list items seem to jump up and down in a disorienting way), this is really trivial to do by animating height with AnimatedContainer. The existence of a separate AnimatedList widget and ImplicitlyAnimatedList plugin threw me off a bit.